# How to restart failed jobs in Sidekiq?

Tags: sidekiq

I'd like to restart all failed jobs using the rails console. Is there a way to do this? I can get a list of the jobs using:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
Sidekiq::Queue.new("mailers")
```

But at that point i'm now sure how to restart them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Failed jobs aren't enqueued, they are in the retry set (the Retries tab in the Web UI).  Sidekiq will retry those jobs periodically.

If you want to retry all pending retries immediately, you can do this:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.retry_all
```